# Iterating through MySQL rows

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL table made up of words and an associated number.  The numbers are unique for each word.  I want to find the **first word** whose index is larger than a given number.  As an example:

```
-----------------------
| WORD:    | F_INDEX: |
|---------------------|
| a        | 5        |
| cat      | 12       |
| bat      | 4002     |
-----------------------
```

If I was given the number "9" I would want "cat" returned, as it is the first word whose index is larger than 9.

I know that I can get a full list of sorted rows by querying:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY f_index;
```

But would, instead, like to make a MySQL query that does this.  (The confusion lies in the fact that I'm unsure as to how to keep track of the current row in my query).  I know can loop with something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE looper(desired_index INT)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE current_index int DEFAULT 0
    // Loop here, setting current_index to whatever the next rows index is, 
    // then do a comparison to check it to our desired_index, breaking out 
    // if it is greater.
END;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.word
     , t.f_index
  FROM table_name t
 WHERE t.f_index > 9 
 ORDER 
    BY t.f_index
 LIMIT 1
```

It is much more efficient to have the database return the row you need, than it is to pull a whole bunch of rows and figure out which one you need.

For best performance of this query, you will want an index `ON table_name (f_index,word)`.

Comment: I.. was not aware this was a thing.  Perfect!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use MYSQL statement to retrieve the first item you found from f_index where the f_index is greater than the value your pass in.

For example :

```
select word from table_name
where f_index > desired_index
order by f_index
limit 1
```